# Mass conversion of error codes to exceptions

Tags: c#, c++, exception, error-handling

I have a low-level class that imports external C++ functions, such as:

```
public static class LowLevel
{
    [DllImport("DLLName.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int DoStuff([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string parameter);

    [DllImport("DLLName.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int DoStuff2(int parameter);
    ...
}
```

Now, it has a lot of methods and all of them return an error code. I'd like to encapsulate and convert these error codes to exceptions i.e.:

```
public static void DoStuff(string parameter)
{
        int error = LowLevel.DoStuff(parameter);
        if (error != 0)
            throw new MyException(error);
}
```

Is there a way to do this for a lot of methods without a ton of copy pasting? And is it even a good idea in general or is there a better way? I'm trying to avoid having to pass error codes through all protected to public, low level to mid level to high level abstraction classes, before finally showing an error message etc.

Comment: This is what shell or Perl scripts are for. This is a fairly common approach with free software on Linux. The source code typically has a metadata file of some kind, in XML, YAML, or a homebrew format. As part of building the code a shell or a Perl script runs it and robo-generates declarations or data structures, which are then compiled. Unfortunately, the Microsoft Windows platform is not as robust when it comes to support for script-based development tools, and preference for pointy-clicky-GUI type of things.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: That's blatant nonsense. Integrating a custom script into your build process that generates some code before it's compiled is trivial and support exists even in GUI tools such as Visual Studio. Whether it's the best solution to the problem is another question, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you should probably ask yourself for each of those instances is whether a non-zero return value is actually equivalent to an exception or maybe an expected result. Not every method that has different results uses those to communicate exceptional circumstances and if you map those into exceptions, flow control gets ... weird.

Your wrapper looks fine-ish (missing documentation, I guess). One thing I'd probably do would be to use sensible exceptions depending on what the failure code means, e.g. throw a `FileNotFoundException` instead of `MyException(2)`. This precludes pretty much any automated approach, though.

As for automating this, [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) allows you to define quick fixes based on a pattern search. This can help in at least auto-generating some of the boilerplate.

Another option would be [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), Microsoft's open-source C# compiler framework. Visual Studio 2015 allows you to write quick fixes with Roslyn's API if you want something integrated in the IDE (similar to what ReSharper provides with what I mentioned above). But you can also use the libraries to just write a small tool that generated the appropriate glue code.

Other options for code generation would be [T4 templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb126445.aspx) which at least Visual Studio knows how to auto-regenerate if necessary (although that won't be done in the build files). I also used PowerShell in the past to generate source code. In one case by looking at a compiled assembly and generating code based on the types and methods in a certain namespace (enumerating that via reflection), which could work here with your `LowLevel` class as well.

---

Auto-generated code is a bit of a tricky thing, though. If you need to make changes to the generated code, then your options are fewer or you need to creatively use partial classes, or branches and merges in your source control system to avoid clobbering manually-written code with regenerated code.

My suggestion here would be to completely separate generated code from handwritten code on a file level. Doing otherwise just creates unnecessary headaches. All that assumes, of course, that you may run the code generation process more often than just once.

Comment: The C++ library is essentially a HW driver, so all non-zero codes are unexpected results, except maybe 1-2 that could occur daily, but handling them separately won't make flow control too bad.

You bring up good point with the FileNotFoundException, I think I'll do it manually, since I do not have Resharper and other forms of automation would probably take equally as long to set up. Also I can double up and get rid of some marshalling this way (stringbuilders to strings, ints to enums etc.).

Comment: It probably comes down to how many methods there are, how much time it takes to do manually, how comfortable you are with various options of scripting all that and what time it'd take to do that. At work I used code generation (using PowerShell and reflection) for automatically implementing various visitor implementations over a syntax tree. When we add classes or properties we can simply regenerate the visitors. In this case the generator was about a day of work and as a benefit we cannot forget to copy certain properties over, etc. I've used T4 in the same project to generate a few tests.